# Loop Redirect - .htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

i am trying to solve an issue on my localhost.

i have a script that is using following .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /agg/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/agg/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /agg/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

"agg" is the folder on the localhost where files are stored.

(full path: C:\wamp\www\agg)

when i try to access http://localhost/agg/ it gives me "This webpage has a redirect loop" error.

apache rewrite_module is on, php version is 5.4.12

there is also a file called "config.php" that have the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$siteurl = "http://localhost";

//.... etc
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule is the culprit, causing this loop. Have this code in `/agg/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /agg/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```